# Getting error: 'SCHED_IDLE' undeclared when trying to compile cyclictest

Tags: linux-kernel, real-time, embedded-linux

When I try and compile [Cyclictest](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Cyclictest), I get the following:

`error: 'SCHED_IDLE' undeclared`

I am using linux kernel 3.14 from the following:

`ftp.embeddedarm.com/ts-socket-macrocontrollers/ts-4700-linux/cross-toolchains/arm-2008q3.tar.gz`

and cross-compiling for my board.   I am using the following from the command line, but it fails every time. According to what I read, the 3.14 kernel and greater should have the Scheduler, so not sure why it is failing.

`export CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/toolchains/arm-2008q3/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc`

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried to look on Google first? https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/issues/26

Comment: Thanks for the reminder?  I found that,  but did you read where I said that i checked and my 3.14 kernel is supposed to have it....   i thought I had a code  question,  but  it might be a kernel question.

Comment: Ok. Can you add instructions to your question, describing how you obtained sources (repo, branch) and built them, so that we can reproduce your issue. It's hard to answer your question, when there is no way to observe your particular actions and sources you used.